# python virtual env issue

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, ckan

While using command `pipenv shell` to create virtual env for project it shows below error:

```
“Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /opt/fiware-env/ckan/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3.5 (3.5.2) to create virtualenv...
✘ Failed creating virtual environment

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 133, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .plugin.activators import ActivationSelector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/run/plugin/activators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import ComponentBuilder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/run/plugin/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from importlib_metadata import entry_points
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 88
    dist: Optional['Distribution'] = None
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Failed to create virtual environment.”
```

using python version 3.5.2
Any suggestions would be great. Thank you

Comment: You should be using the `venv` module with Python 3.5

Comment: yes , i used these commands 
1. apt-get install python3-venv
2. python3 -m venv venv
3. pipenv shell

Comment: Uh, why are you using `pipenv shell`? Once you created your virtual environment with `python3 -m venv venv`, run `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: OSError: Command /usr/lib/ckan/venv/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 2
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2

Comment: i m using python2 env still getting above error

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3??? It seems you have both on your machine and mix them

Comment: yes there is complications of python 2 and python3 on machine . Thank you for your help